# Do i know how much gas fee for testnet will be on mainnet?

Tags: transactions, fees

I am currently testing the smart contract on Polygon's testnet Mumbai.

I think the transaction gas fee measured on the testnet will be different from the gas fee paid on the mainnet.

I would like to know how much the transaction fee on the testnet comes from the mainnet.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No transaction fee from the mainnet comes to the testnet or vice versa.

Testnet, as the name suggests, is only for testing, and there is no real value in assets over the network (apart from helping the developers & users check their DApps and how things work.)

Mainnet, as the name suggests, is the primary one, which has assets with value. Thus, each transaction has some amount of cost associated with it.

To know about the transaction fees at a particular time for the Polygon Blockchain, you can use a service like [PolygonScan GasTracker](https://polygonscan.com/gastracker).

Nevertheless, you can see how much Gas is used in the testnet to derive the value for the mainnet. Gas is calculated as:

`Gas = Gas Used * Gas Price`

(There is Base Fee, etc., in it, but for simplification, you can use the above equation.)

Now, to calculate the fee on Mainnet, you can take the Gas Used from the transaction in Testnet and multiply it with the Gas Price based on the link shared above.